# How do I split a string in 2 with a colon in?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, split, type-conversion

I have a textbox with an entry field, in which a user inputs time in a 00:00 format (HH:mm). What I would like to do is extract 2 integers from the string, the Hours (20:00 = 20 hours) and the minutes (00:20 = 20 minutes).

To clear things up, I tried using the string.Split() method with ":" as my delimiter. I was fetching my string from a TextMeshProUGUI Input Field in unity and when Split(); the resulting substring wouldn't convert into an Integer for some reason so I settled on using 2 separate (LEGACY) InputFields, one for hours one for minutes which works but is clunky.

I'm going to re-try my single InputField using the Legacy UI and the string.Split() method explained here.

Comment: What don't you understand about `string.Split()`?

Comment: Have you looked at any examples of using `string.Split()`?  Made any attempt at all?  What didn't work as expected?

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is: What data format should I expect. If you want to get a `TimeSpan` ( wrapper around time ) then you can simply use `TimeSpan.ParseExact`

Comment: @gunr2171 I looked at 3 webpage walkthroughs on string.Split(). All 3 applied the method to (relatively) complex problems that were miles away from the simple action I required. This disparity, as well as running out of Ritalin 4 days ago, made the code melt together. So I thought I would ask for a direct answer, as having an answer to a problem makes it easier to understand completely, and then apply that knowledge to further learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the TimeSpan.Parse() function to convert the string to a TimeSpan.
Not the fastest method, but it's clean.

```cs
string time = "20:20";
if (TimeSpan.TryParse(time, out TimeSpan timespan))
{
    // Do something with:
    // timespan.Hours
    // timespan.Minutes
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "not the fastest", it's plenty quick and with basically any performance question, people overestimate how much it matters. I'd also suggest using ParseExact rather than just Parse.

Answer (score 1):

Extending my comment into an answer. It seems like you're about to parse a string into a time which you can achieve with `TimeSpan` class and extract needed informations easily. For that you need to know what format your time input is and how you want to process it. Judging by your code I can assume you always expect a format of `hh:mm` which indicates that first part is an hour in 2 digit format ( either `02:mm` or `14:mm` ), same with minutes. This alone solves most of your problems because you can just parse your string into `TimeSpan` using [`ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact) method:

```
// first, create a format you want to be used
const string FORMAT = "hh:mm";

// now just use TimeSpan.ParseExact method to retrieve your data
var result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(YourTextBoxText, FORMAT);
```

This will return a `TimeSpan` which has properties like `Hours`, `Minutes` etc. which you can then use to retrieve whatever time value you want.

---

EDIT: Things to note are that the above can throw a bunch of exceptions depending on the data input, formats etc. It's up to you if you're about to make any custom logic based on exception or whatever. Exceptions you might need to include in your logic and be aware of are

- `ArgumentNullException` - thrown whenever argument is null,
- `FormatException` - thrown whenever text input is in invalid format

For more info about `TimeSpan` you shold refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan)